# Ros concert halts on adding remote machine

Tags: ros, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going through [basic tutorial for setting up distributed chatter concert.](http://wiki.ros.org/chatter_concert/Tutorials/indigo/Chatter%20Concert%20-%20Distributed).
However, on step 3.3 the launch halts.

EDIT1: similar warnings are received on (successful) launching of local nodes, so I guess that is not the issue

<strike>The info (and possible cause of trouble) that I get is:</strike>

> Rapp Manager : disabling apps requiring capabilities [Couldn't find capability server node. Error: Node 'capability_server' not found.]

> Rapp Manager : 'rocon_apps/chirp' is not unique and has no preferred rapp. rocon_apps/moo_chirp' has been selected.

The last received info is about Rapp manager initialised, and what usually follows (in successful, local launches) is the info about *adding connection to public interface*. Could that be a trouble? How could I inspect it further?
I run it on Ubuntu 14.04, ros indigo, and installed rocon via package manager.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228594/ros-concert-halts-on-adding-remote-machine/) by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 526 on 2016-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-03-14**:
actually, the behaviour is the same as one that can be seen locally when no concert is launch, but dude is launched. that means that remote machine can't detect existing concerts? what could be possible reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was not in the ros or concert, but in the fact that my wireless network had some restrictions on broadcasting.
The solution for the problem was to create an ad hoc wireless network (as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html), for example) and then the tutorial worked as described.

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1